# Building a basic framework

Tags: javascript

I am trying to build a very basic JS framework for my own uses, ultimately collating a lot of pieces of JavaScript I have created over the years. But I would not call myself a JavaScript expert.

What I have written below works well enough but I really would like to know if I am making any fundamental errors in the way this is set up, rather than re-writing a lot of code further down the line.

This basic start point is mirroring the way jQuery can be written to select an element and chain an event to that object, but using all the `querySelectorAll` instead of the older methods.

If anyone can find basic or advanced flaws in what I've done that would be most useful.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">

///DO NOT COPY OR USE FOR COMMERCIAL PURPOSES
function Framework(sel) {

    function myFramework(sel) {

        ///Add selections to array 

        this.sel = sel;

        if (typeof this.sel !== "undefined") {

            if (typeof this.sel !== 'string') {
                this.selArray = new Array(this.sel);
            } else {
                this.what = this.sel.charAt(0);

                if (this.what == ".") {
                    this.selArray = document.querySelectorAll(this.sel);
                } else if (this.what == "[") {
                    this.selArray = document.querySelectorAll(this.sel);
                } else if (this.what == "#") {
                    this.sel = this.sel.substr(1);
                    this.selArray = new Array(document.getElementById(this.sel));
                }
            }
        }

        myFramework.prototype.ready = function (func) {

            document.onreadystatechange = function () {
                var state = document.readyState
                if (state == 'interactive') {
                    //  init();
                } else if (state == 'complete') {
                    func();
                }
            }
        }

        myFramework.prototype.click = function (func) {
            for (i = 0; i < this.selArray.length; i++) {

                if (window.addEventListener) {
                    this.selArray[i].addEventListener('click', func, false);
                } else if (window.attachEvent) {
                    this.selArray[i].attachEvent('onclick', func);
                }
            }

            return this;
        }

        return this;
    }

    return newTask = new myFramework(sel);
}


Framework().ready(function () {
    Framework('.test').click(function () {
        alert("it works!");
    });
});


</script>
</head>

<body>
    <div style="background-color:#FFFF00; height:10px" class="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `///DO NOT COPY OR USE FOR COMMERCIAL PURPOSES` You do know that posting a question on a Stack Exchange is under cc by-sa 3.0. I am not a lawyer and don't know anything really about license or anything related to it, but I just wanted to make you aware of that fact.

Comment: @Marc-Andre was [already mentioned](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26530807/builiding-a-basic-framework-does-this-look-like-it-will-work#comment41688232_26530807) on the  (now on hold) [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26530807/1803692), you're fighting a lost war...

Comment: @Marc-Andre What baffles me is why the OP, a self-confessed inexperienced JS programmer, writing a "basic framework," feels the need to try and protect their IP given all of the high quality open source software libraries and frameworks all over the internet.

Comment: Maybe just worry about something else, there are bigger issues in the world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you've got is not a framework. It is a library.

I can see you are basically creating a jQuery-like wrapper for selecting DOM nodes and event handling. Nothing terribly wrong with the main idea.

Why have a function called `Framework` which has a function inside of it? Every call to `Framework(...)` causes `myFramework` to be recreated. Instead, just use a regular prototype-based "class" in JavaScript:

```
function Framework(sel) {
    if (!(this instanceof Framework)) {
        // return a new Framework object if called without the "new" keyword
        return new Framework(sel);
    }

    this.sel = sel;

    if (this.sel) {
        if (typeof this.sel !== 'string') {
            this.selArray = new Array(this.sel);
        } else {
            this.what = this.sel.charAt(0);

            if (this.what == ".") {
                this.selArray = document.querySelectorAll(this.sel);
            } else if (this.what == "[") {
                this.selArray = document.querySelectorAll(this.sel);
            } else if (this.what == "#") {
                this.sel = this.sel.substr(1);
                this.selArray = new Array(document.getElementById(this.sel));
            }
        }
    }
}

Framework.prototype = {
    constructor: Framework,

    ready: function(func) {
        // ...
    },

    click: function(func) {
        // ...
    }
};
```

The code that inspects the selector and calls querySelectorAll or getElementById is completely redundant and unneeded. If `this.sel` is a string, just blindly pass it to `document.querySelectorAll`. You've gained nothing by inspecting the selector. The speed difference between getElementById("foo") and querySelectorAll("#foo") will be negligible at worst, so why complicate your code?

```
if (this.sel) {
    this.selArray = typeof this.sel === "string"
        ? document.querySelectorAll(this.sel)
        : [this.sel];
}
```

### Optimizing The Attaching Of Events

In your code, you loop over the array of elements, and on each iteration you test for `attachEvent` or `addEventListener`. Browsers won't magically change their native DOM API, so testing for these methods repeatedly when the result will be the same is extra work for the browser. Instead, create a method that does the event binding, which we will call `bind`.

Instead of testing for the "attachEvent" method on each iteration of the loop in `click`, test it once:

```
Framework.prototype = {
    constructor: Framework,

    ready: function(func) {
        // ...
    },

    click: function(func) {
        for (var i = 0; i < this.selArray.length; i++) {
            this.bind(this.selArray[i], "click", func);
        }

        return this;
    },

    bind: !!document.addEventListener
        ? function(element, event, func) {
            element.addEventListener(event, func, false);
            return this;
        }
        : function(element, event, func) {
            element.attachEvent(event, "on" + func);
            return this;
        }
};
```

The bind method is set on the `prototype` and makes use of a ternary operator to assign a function to the `bind` property that supports the current browser's native API instead of checking for support.

```
       // The Test: Does the browser have a document.addEventListener method?
    bind: !!document.addEventListener

     // Yes: The browser does. Use this function to bind events using standard API
        ? function(element, event, func) {
            element.addEventListener(event, func, false);
            return this;
        }

     // No: The browse does not. Use Internet Explorer's API
        : function(element, event, func) {
            element.attachEvent(event, "on" + func);
            return this;
        }
```

The decision to use `attachEvent` or `addEventListener` is made once at page load. The `Framework.prototype.bind` method will directly use the supported API for each browser rather than test for it.

More information on ternary operators: [Conditional (ternary) Operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator)

### Implicitly Declared Global Variables

Don't forget that variable assignments without `var` before the variable name create implicitly declared global variables. The `for` loop in the click method does this with the `i` variable, and your original `Framework` method mysteriously declares a global variable `newTask`.

Comment: That's fantastic Greg, I didn't even know about that constructor syntax.

Comment: I'm a bit confused about the bind method for event listeners isn't this method being called in the loop anyway or does this have to do with memory management?

Comment: could you maybe explain this shorthand it's not something I recognise at least not the square brackets and line after the if statement... this.selArray = typeof this.sel === "string"
        ? document.querySelectorAll(this.sel)
        : [this.sel];

Comment: Sure thing, Guesser. Let me update my answer.

Comment: Is calling the method "bind" not a bit confusing with this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind

Comment: Or [this](http://api.jquery.com/bind/), really. jQuery has a `bind` method as well, so I guess that was my inspiration since your original code is a simple implementation of the same programming pattern jQuery was modeled after. You could just as easily call it "attach", "addEvent" or "listen".

Comment: ok cool,thanks for all this feedback, very useful.